# Data is not getting updated in ajax beforeSend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to add update accessToken value in beforeSend of ajax. But that value is not getting reflected in " data ". What's wrong with this code.

```
var accessToken ;    
$.ajax({
            url : "some_url",
            method : "GET",
            beforeSend: function() {
                accessToken = accessTokens.getAccessToken();
                console.log(accessToken);
            },
            data : {
                access_token : accessToken
            },
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
        });
```

Comment: `beforeSend` happens at a stage in the request, before the request is made, but after the options have been given to ajax.  Ref. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  Checkout the beforeSend option, the second argument given to it is the options for the request you should be able to manipulate

Comment: is there any other way to update "access_token" variable other that giving it outside ?

Comment: You should be able to modify it on the settings passed into the beforeSend method.

Comment: or just do `data: { access_token: accessTokens.getAccessToken() }`